# Split shell-like syntax in Haskell?

Tags: python, haskell, split, lexical-analysis, shlex

How can I split a string in shell-style syntax in Haskell? The equivalent in Python is [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

```py
>>> shlex.split('''/nosuchconf "/this doesn't exist either" "yep"''')
['/nosuchconf', "/this doesn't exist either", 'yep']
```

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory answer to this question?

Comment: @RichardCook No, I don't believe so. It's been awhile tho.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean: are you wanting to get get all quoted sub-strings from a String?  Note that unlike Python, etc. Haskell only has one set of quotes that indicate something is a String, namely `"..."`.

Possibilities to consider:

- The [words](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3awords) and [lines](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alines) functions
- The [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package
- Write a custom parser using polyparse, uu-parsinglib, parsec, etc.

It may be useful if you specified why you wanted such functionality: are you trying to parse existing shell scripts?  Then [language-sh](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-sh) might be of use.  But you shouldn't be using such Strings internally in Haskell, and instead using `[String]` or something.

Comment: The shell delimited string is the value of an option in a INI-style config file.

Comment: @MattJoiner:If you want to read in an INI-style config file, see [hsini](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsini) and [ConfigFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConfigFile).

Comment: Yes I'm already using ConfigFile... The value of an option is this shell string...

Comment: @MattJoiner: oh, and it doesn't already do this split for you?  You may be able to get John Goerzen to add support for parsing such values for you (since ConfigFile is already using parsec).

Answer (score 0):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shellwords

```
λ> import ShellWords
λ> parse "/nosuchconf \"/this doesn't exist either\" \"yep\""
Right ["/nosuchconf","/this doesn't exist either","yep"]
```